# How to create a new character variable in SAS from the formats applied to a numeric variable OR How to import SPSS value labels only

Tags: import, sas, format, spss, recode

I have a series of formatted numeric variables and I would like to convert them all into character variables assigned the corresponding values found in the format labels. Here is an example of the format:

```
proc format;
    value Group
        1= 'Experimental 1'
        2= 'Experimental 2'
        3= 'Treatment as usual';
run;
```

My variable Group_num has values 1-3 and has this format applied. I want to create a new character variable called Group_char which has the values "Experimental 1", "Experimental 2", and "Treatment as usual".

The (long) way I would do this would be:

```
data out;
set in;
format Group_char $30.;
if Group_num=1 then Group_char="Experimental 1";
if Group_num=2 then Group_char="Experimental 2";
if Group_num=3 then Group_char="Treatment as usual";
run;
```

However, I need to do this to 13 different variables and I don't know what their variable values, format names, and format labels are without looking at the data more. Preferably, I would want to use whatever format is already applied to the variable to automatically translate it into a new character variable, without needing to know the format name/labels or original variable values. However, if I need to find out the format name to create a new character variable just by using the format name, that would be better than needing to also know the original variables values and format labels as well.

Alternatively, another way to solve my problem would be if you could tell me if there is a way of importing SPSS datasets using variable value labels only, and leaving the values themselves out of the picture entirely, such that numeric variables with value labels are imported as character variables.

Thank you

Comment: You need to show example of what you have  data, formats etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it's usually best not to do this - most of the time that you need the character bits, you can get them off of the formats.

But, that said... you need to look at the `vvalue` function.

```
data want;
  set have;
  var_char = vvalue(var_num);
run;
```

`vvalue` returns the formatted value of the argument.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the function I was hoping for. I agree that usually this isn't something I would want to do. I exclusively wanted it for data reconciliation across a series of SPSS datasets with variables that have similar names (e.g. Gender_ID and GenderID). Because I am importing SPSS datasets, SAS generates format names automatically at the import stage, in order to retain the value labels and convert them to formats. Since the variables all have similar names, the auto-generated format names wind up with duplicates (continued...)

Comment: (continued)  (e.g. Gender_ID and GenderID both get assigned format GenderA) and accordingly the format created for dataset A gets applied to a variable in both dataset A and dataset B, for example. Rather than trying to use FMTLIB to store the formats separately, which I haven't figured out how to use successfully in the past, I wanted a quick workaround such that when I import each dataset I immediately convert the numeric variable to character, before importing the next dataset and running into the format name problem. Thank you for providing this solution!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  It is certainly possible to deal with the format issue if you want - feel free to open a new question about that; although there is a bigger possible issue in that you could have a format for two different datasets with the same name but different values, and _that_ isn't really possible to deal with without changing the format (possible, but irritating).

Comment: Exactly! Importing multiple SPSS datasets without dealing with this was making variables show up as having formatted values that were simply incorrect / not in line with the value labels assigned in SPSS. My team requires SPSS datasets, and on a prior large cleaning project this was enough of an issue that I had to change my approach to only deal with one dataset at a time and clear SAS work/format libraries between every import. This data reconciliation task is small and I'm only creating 1 permanent variable so the impracticality of converting numeric vars to character is inconsequential

Comment: I did once post about this question and got helpful responses, but ultimately using syntax was super tedious/lengthy and it seemed like not enough of it could be automated in a way that felt sufficiently intuitive for me to make it worthwhile to deal with multiple very wide datasets at once via syntax, and the best solution was to only deal with one dataset at a time. Thank you again, this function will definitely come in handy in the future.